# You are getting tired, you should find a parking place to rest

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

When doing long trips, you will eventually start getting 'tired' in game. This is shown to you by a message that takes up your GPS space saying "You are getting tired. You shold find a parking place to rest".

I have noticed that the screen will occasionally start blacking out but I have always rested before it got too bad.

Once this message starts showing, how long can you keep driving until you fall asleep?

Do you actually fall asleep at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shortly after you've passed the time when the game says it's time for rest (F6 menu) it will begin charging you 150 euro every few minutes until you sleep.  Not a big deal if you have an empire, but if you're still getting established it's worth knowing.

The only time you should drive while tired is when taking a rest break would cause you to deliver your cargo late.

Comment: thx i hadn't noticed this happening

Answer (score 10):

At first you will begin audibly yawning. Once this phase passes the screen will begin getting darker and the word dozing will appear in the middle of the screen every now and again.

The yawning will get increasingly more frequent.

The text will change to "You are tired! You should find somewhere to park and rest!".

The dozing screens will get longer the longer you stay awake

You don't seem to actually fall asleep (I drove 300 miles while tired)

Comment: At which point does it start charging you?

Answer (score 1):

If I am within 2-3 hours of my destination, there's no way I'm pulling over for 8 hours because the game tells me I'm tired.  I'll rest when I'm dead.

Anyway, usually the 150 euro penalties start rolling in right when you hit your destination anyway.  Bang out that parking job extra quick and you usually only get a single one.  I haven't fallen asleep at all yet.